# CanCanCan rescue_from not catching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```

I have this inside of my ApplicationController and it still doesn't catch `CanCan::AccessDenied in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard`

Comment: why would it catch the exception from the controller that out of your control :) the rails admin controllers doesn't have any "authorize" calls.

Comment: Rails Admin and CanCanCan all tell me this should work just fine. I remove rails admin, same thing happens. The rescue_from isn't catching.

Comment: Is the root_url also denied? What if you redirect to a static page or add a log message before the redirection?

Comment: @RoaringStones According to [docs](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCanCan#handle-unauthorized-access) what he's done above should work

Comment: @ZekeDran yes, if the application controller where the catch happens is a base controller for a controller where the raise emerged. and that _could_ not be true for the active admin controllers. (I'm not sure myself)

Comment: how could it possibly work in Rails-4: if they inherited admin controller from application controller, it should work in all versions... **Any removal of middleware possibly causes this?** `rails-api` aggressively removed unwanted middleware for apis